# Why does $\int_{-1}^1 ((1-x^2)(P_m'P_n-P_n'P_m))'\,dx = 0$ for Legendre polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, legendre-polynomials

I was looking at a proof of the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials in Lebedev's [Special Functions and their Applications](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486606244.html):

[image]

I can't understand why the integral of the first term vanishes. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Start by finding the antiderivative of the first term (this should easy since the entire term is given as a derivative). Then evaluate the result at -1 and 1 (evaluating the Legendre polynomials exactly will turnout to be less important for the problem).

Comment: It follows from $\int_{-1}^{1} F'(x) dx = F(1) - F(-1)$ for any $C^{1}$ function $F$.

Comment: There's a typo in your title that would make this trivial.

Comment: I was ignoring the outer prime for some reason. Must be tired!

Comment: @J.G. It is trival!

Comment: @LukeCollins I was referring to something I just fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \Big((1 - x^2)(P_m'P_n - P_n'P_m) \Big)' \mathrm{d}x = \Big[(1 - x^2)(P_m'P_n - P_n'P_m)\Big]_{-1}^1 $$
$$= \Big[(1 - 1^2)(P_m'(1)P_n(1) - P_n'(1)P_m(1))\Big] - \Big[(1 - (-1)^2)(P_m'(-1)P_n(-1) - P_n'(-1)P_m(-1))\Big]$$
$$ = \Big[(0)(P_m'(1)P_n(1) - P_n'(1)P_m(1))\Big] - \Big[(0)(P_m'(-1)P_n(-1) - P_n'(-1)P_m(-1))\Big] $$
$$= 0 - 0 $$
$$= 0 $$

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I was ignoring the outer prime. Oh well, time for bed.